# What are the possibilities of having sexual encounters during stay at a hotel?

Tags: hotels, regulations

I have never been to any tourist destination. I just wanted to ask this question.

Comment: If you're traveling with a partner, could be fairly high, perhaps less so if you're married, and close to zero if the kids are sharing the room.

Comment: You need to add details to your question for it to be answerable.

Comment: Or do you mean unwanted sexual encounters?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be asked in http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sex-and-intimacy?

Comment: I mean along the lines of an attempted rape / groping / similar event.

Comment: I was going to add a Van Wilder Quip but ....

Comment: That is up to you. You rent the hotel room so you can do whatever you like. Getting strangers into the room is up to the hotel policy. If you are staying in a hostel, *please* don't. I met a girl who even missed a flight because of the noises and she couldn't sleep hearing them.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are asking about having a sexual encounter with a stranger. It seems to me it is up to the hotel to allow strangers in the rooms or not. It could also depend on the local laws.

Once my Father was staying at a hotel, I tried to visit him, but the hotel forbid me to go to his room! They said that only registered guests could go to the hotel, even if I could show an ID which stated that he really was my Father.